# How can I set Streambuilder with a fix list of items

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use a Listview with a fix list of items from a Streambuilder. Not the count of items are changing but the properties of them.
At the moment I check the snapshot data and build an else widget tree.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {}
else ...
```

Is there a better way?

I tried also to put the fix items to the stream controller before I listen to the stream but without success.

@Edit:
Fix means that I have the count of data and a skeleton of data before the first data properties arrives from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's pretty much the right way to go when you are working with Stream data.

1. Check if data is there
2. Check if there are any errors in the stream
3. If data exists and no errors exist, use the stream data.

https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/working-with-bloc-using-reactive-programming

Comment: Hm, you are thinking you have the right way. There is no right or wrong but only ways.

Comment: of course. right and wrong depends upon what your goal is.

Comment: By the way I asked for something very concrete and not for reactive programming. It seems for me that you want to promote something.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. Streambuilder has [initialData property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/initialData.html).

Now I can delete the redudant code in the case of !hasData because I set the fix data as initialData.
At the moment the first data arrives from the stream the data are automatically replaced.